# Laravel 4.2 Eloquent get posts (events) between dates

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Lets say I have event which start date is 2015-07-30 (today) and end date is 2015-08-01. Ok, I want to see tomorrow events. How show this event at 2015-07-31?

I already tried with this:

```
$tomorrow = Carbon::tomorrow(); // 2015-07-31 00:00:00
$dayAfterTomorrow = Carbon::tomorrow()->addDay(); // 2015-08-01 00:00:00
$events = $events->where(function ($query) use ($tomorrow, $dayAfterTomorrow) {     
                $query->orWhereBetween('start_date', [$tomorrow, $dayAfterTomorrow]);
                $query->orWhereBetween('end_date', [$tomorrow, $dayAfterTomorrow]);
});
```

That query doesn't show event for tomorrow date, because tomorrow day is 2015-07-31 and event end date is 2015-08-31. Maybe I need to use if clauses? If it even possible

Comment: ... so what is `$tomorrow` equal to and what is `$dayAfterTomorrow` equal to... please [edit] into question this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$events = $events->where(function ($query) use ($start, $end) {                
    $query->where('start_date', '<', $end)
          ->where('end_date', '>=', $start);
});
```

> All events where the start_date is less than $end and the end_date is greater than or equal to $start.

If you count as `$start = TOMORROW` and `$end = DAY_AFTER_TOMORROW` than you can see that it will grab ALL events created before the `$end` and then it will only keep the ones where the end is greater than the `$start`. So events created on `2014-04-01` and end on `2015-07-31` will still be included. But events created for `2015-08-01` and end later than that will not.

Comment: Yes, it's also wrong because end_date is 2015-08-01 and $end = 2015-07-31

Comment: Yea i just figured out the best way to go about this. I will fix now.

Comment: yea I am struggling with some stupid logic that makes me realize it misses it. I'm goign to try again with this answer.. cheers so far...

Comment: At this point I hope this works. But I don't have a second to test so I need you now.

Comment: @BeG I have gone through like 9 different types of solutions and I think finally this one is right for your attempt.